# In Doxygen, how can I reference a C++ user-defined literal?

Tags: c++, c++11, doxygen

I have a pair of functions documented with Doxygen. One is a user-defined literal; I want to reference it in my Doxygen comments; using `operator""_hash()` or `operator"" _hash()` does not work:

```
//! @see operator""_hash()
constexpr std::size_t static_string_hash(const char* data, std::size_t count);

constexpt std::size_t operator"" _hash(const char* data, std::size_t count);
```

How can I reference this routine in my Doxygen comment ?

Comment: AFAIK Doxygen does not support user defined literals yet.

Comment: @pmr you are right, I just checked the [ChangeLog](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/changelog.html) and it only mentions string literals :-/